# Using getTag and setTag to hold ListItem Values

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I am learning about getTag and setTag. I need explanation about these methods and want to know how they work.
I have made a simple CustomListView having two buttons and one textview.
Buttons are add and subtract which increment or decrements the value of counter but the problem is that only the last item value is changing. Please give me a solution as well as a good explanation
Thanks .

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_items, null);
            add = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.add);
            sub = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sub);
            textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.numberTV);
            convertView.setTag(new ViewHolder(add, sub, textView , count));
        }
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        textView = holder.textView;
        count = holder.counter;
        add = holder.add;
        sub = holder.sub;
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                count +=1;
                textView.setText(String.valueOf(count));
            }
        });
        sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                count -=1;
                textView.setText(String.valueOf(count));
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
}

class ViewHolder {

    Button add, sub;
    TextView textView;
int counter = 0;
    public ViewHolder(Button add, Button sub, TextView textView , int counter) {
        this.add = add;
        this.sub = sub;
        this.counter = counter;
        this.textView = textView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `custom listview adapter` what you are trying to implement is `recycling` of the `single item (list_items)` showed in the `Listview`. and because of which you require to use the `getTag` and `setTag` methods to that View.

So why do you require these method in the first place...

1. You are trying to recycle the `list_items` and view's inside it, to do that you are making the `ViewHolder` which will hold the inner references of views inside the `list_items`.
2. You don't want to call `inflater` and referencing on Views every-time `getView` is called so you save the `ViewHolder's` instance to the View, which will be used again without re-inflating the `list_items` and references inside it.
3. By `setTag()` you can attach as Object to the `View`
4. By `getTag()` you can get back the Object attached to the `View`

So this way you are recycling the same initialization of your `list_items` every time `getView()` is called

Seems like a lot of work, Use `RecyclerView`.

your solution for the code... you may check the code on [gitHub](https://github.com/pankajnimgade/Tutorial/blob/master/app/src/main/java/listview/test/activities/ListViewTestFiveActivity.java)

```
public class ListViewTestFiveActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view_test_five);


        initializeUI();
    }

    private void initializeUI() {
        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListViewTestFiveActivity_listView);
        ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            Item item = new Item();
            item.setCount(i);
            items.add(item);
        }

        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.single_item_listview_five, items);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

        private ArrayList<Item> items;
        private Context a_context;
        private LayoutInflater a_layoutInflater;

        public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Item> items) {
            super(context, resource, items);
            this.a_context = context;
            this.items = items;
            a_layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.a_context);
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;
            ViewHolder holder = null;
            if (row == null) {
                row = a_layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_item_listview_five, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.plus = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.ListViewTestFiveActivity_plus_button);
                holder.textView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.ListViewTestFiveActivity_count_textView4);
                holder.minus = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.ListViewTestFiveActivity_minus_button);
                row.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
            }

            final Item item = items.get(position);
            holder.textView.setText("" + item.getCount());
            holder.plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int increase_count =item.getCount();
                    item.setCount(++increase_count);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
            holder.minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int decrease_count =item.getCount();
                    item.setCount(--decrease_count );
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
            return row;
        }

        private class ViewHolder{
            Button plus;
            TextView textView;
            TextView minus;
        }
    }

    private class Item {
        int count;

        public int getCount() {
            return count;
        }

        public void setCount(int count) {
            this.count = count;
        }
    }
}
```

> Output [image]